# How do I generate a flash projector file from my FLEX Flash project using Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, projector

Is there something I have to do in the code in order to get this to work?

Is it a build setting in the FLEX project?

Can I do it from the SWF after it's been built in release or debug mode?

I need the projector file so that I can call an external EXE from within the fscommand subdirectory using the fscommand function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what a Flash Projector File is; then you cannot create one from Flash Builder.

You can, however, create an AIR app and use Captive Runtime to create a .EXE file from a windows machine.  From within the AIR Application; you can use [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) to execute an external EXE file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not want to use AIR. I know there used to be a way to create a projector from an SWF file but it appears Adobe has discontinued that feature in the newest Flash Players. Anyone know why they may have stopped this? It is quite annoying because I just want my flex program running through FlashPlayer to be able to execute another EXE.

Comment: I don't understand why you have an aversion to AIR in this case.

Comment: I am tied to legacy code libraries that do not use AIR, I am not familiar with AIR and my app already works. I don't want to create extra work for this scenario just to see how AIR works. This feature isn't that important that I have to mess around with new technology to recreate the app. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: AIR is just everything in the "browser based Flash Player" plus some extrsa which allow tighter integration with the desktop.  The work getting a browser based app to work on the desktop should take less than an hour.  Just create a new project, copy code, and deploy.  Give it 4-6 hours if you want to do some re-architecting to share code between both a browser based app and a desktop app [strongly recommended if that is important]

Answer (score 0):

The information you've received is not true.  Any swf file can be loaded by the FP projector by editing the projects settings to disable the creation of an HTML wrapper.  You can also just copy the swf file generated and open it or use the mxmlc compiler to generate the swf.